# Improving calculate function where input string does not follow normal computational order

Tags: ruby

I am working through some sample interview questions and came across this problem where I have to write a calculate function. The caveat is that the input string isn't written in computational order - instead numbers are first and operators come after.

Test cases:

`calculate("2 3 +") # => 5`

`calculate("12 2 /") #=> 6`

`calculate("48 4 6 * /") # => 2`

```
def calculate(string)
  numbers = string.scan(/\d+/)
  operators = string.scan(/\D\W/).map{|o|o.gsub(" ","")} #TODO Better regex to remove space without having to map

  formatted_string = numbers.inject(""){|string, b| string+"#{b}#{operators.shift}" }

  eval(formatted_string)
end
```

I was able to come up with a solution, but am wondering if there is a more efficient/better way to solve this problem. I don't come from a programming background so I am not familiar with any tools/algorithms that may help.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Saying that the input sting is not written in "logical order" are fighting words to some readers.  You need to think of the operation of a stack.  When you come to an operator, apply it to the element or elements immediately below on the stack, then replace the element or elements, and the operator, with the result, then go up one on the stack.  If it's a number, keep going; else repeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ooh, fun!  This syntax is called [Reverse Polish notation (RPN), aka "postfix notation"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) and is still used by some powerful calculators (the HP-48G made me fall in love with programming!).

The typical way to parse and calculate RPN is to split the input string into whitespace-separated tokens, and for each token, push it onto a stack if it's an integer, otherwise perform the arithmetic operation designated by the token using the last two items on the stack as operands and push the result back on.

Here is a solution I came up with quickly:

```
def calculate(str)
  stack = []
  tokens = str.split(/\s+/)           # Split tokens by whitespace.
  tokens.each do |token|
    if token =~ /^\d+$/               # It's a number
      stack.push(token.to_i)          # ...push it on to the stack.
    elsif %w(+ - * /).include? token  # It's an operator
      a, b = stack.pop(2)             # ...grab the last two numbers
      c = a.send(token, b)            # ...perform the operation
      stack.push(c)                   # ...and push the resulting value.
    else
      raise "invalid token: #{token}" # Punt!
    end
  end
  stack.pop # Return the last value pushed to the stack.
end

calculate("2 3 +")      # => 5, since      2+3 = 5
calculate("12 2 /")     # => 6, since     12/2 = 6
calculate("48 4 6 * /") # => 2, since 48/(4*6) = 2
```

Comment: Good answer, Matthew.  Just one point: the number of operands is not necessarily two.  For example, reversing the sign of a value has just one operand.  Conceivably, there could be operators that take more than two values.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: yes, that's true, and there are unary operators as well (`-`, `sin`, `log`, etc).  Just trying to keep things simple =)

Comment: Thanks for the solution and the link to RPN. Exactly what I was looking for. I'm going to study your solution and will post additional questions if neccessary :)